# Programatically update magento attribututes per store but code is updating all stores

Tags: magento, opencsv, inventory-management

Hello I have a magento multi store setup and have 2 csv files that will be uploaded on a daily bases to update price, qty, and other attributes.

I would like to create two of the following files that run on cron and each file will do the same thing for each store individually.

Currently the code below takes takes store1.csv and applies it to both stores also if i run this code with store3.csv it will apply all price and updates to both stores.

Would like for store1.csv to only update store 1 and store3.csv only update attributes on store 3.

```
 <?php
 /*Move to our working directory
        $home = getenv("HOME");
        if (! $home) {
                chdir('../'); // We hope we are somewhere where this works
        } else {
                chdir($home.'/project/html');
        }*/
    $csv = "store3.csv";
    if (sizeof($argv) > 1) {
        $csv = $argv[1];
    }
//Turn On Error Reporting
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
//BOOTSTRAP MAGENTO
    $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php'; 
    require_once $mageFilename;
    //require_once 'relatedProducts.php';
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->setStoreId(3));
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    umask(0);

//OPEN CSV
    if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            if ($num < 1) continue; // skip blank lines
            $sku = trim($data[0]);
            if ($num < 2) {
              echo "Skipping: ".$sku." not enough fields\n";
              continue;
            }
            $qty = trim($data[1]);
            $price = trim($data[2]);
// grab the product based on sku.
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)->setStoreId(3);
            if(!$product) {
                print "Error:  Invalid SKU, ".$sku."\n";
                continue;
            }
            if ($product->getPrice() != $price) {
              $product->setPrice($price);
              $product->save();
            }
// Grab the inventory(stock) model in order to update quantities.
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->setStoreId(3);
            if ($stockItem->getData('qty') != $qty) {
              $stockItem->setData('qty', $qty);
              if ($qty > 0) {
                $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
              }
              $stockItem->save();
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Price can only be as granular as website level, not storeview level, so you will not be able to set different prices for 2 storesviews that sit in the same website.

Qty is a global field across all stores and websites, so also wont update for each individual store.

For your other attributes, take a look in admin: Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and check what scope they have.

Comment: I tried this with no luck, any other work around or maybe point me to a working script, not module, that does this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: this line is wrong:  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->setStoreId(3)); it should be  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(3);